# How can I show that there cannot exist a homotopy from $\mathcal{C_1}$ to $\mathcal{C_2}$?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the diagram below with an annulus $\mathcal{A}$ and two circles in the annulus $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $\mathcal{C}_2$.

In $\mathbb{R^n}$, there clearly exists a homotopy between any two circles. But if we have this scenario here, where we are restricted by the annulus, it doesn't seem like there exists a homotopy from $\mathcal{C}_1$ to $\mathcal{C}_2$. This is just based on my intuition.

But how can I actually prove this?

[image]

Comment: Any two circles are homeomorpic. Perhaps you mean that there is no auto-homeomorphism of the annulus that, when restricted to $C_1$, is a homeomorphism between $C_1$ and $C_2$. Another interpretation of your question is in the answer by @nitrogen. You should please clarify.

Comment: I have modified my question accordingly. I had intended homotopy, as @nitrogen identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean "homotopy" instead of "homeomorphism".

If that's the case, then you can use the fact that "homotopic" is an equivalence relation, in particular it is transitive.

The circle $\mathcal{C}_2$ is obviously homotopic to the trivial circle. So if you prove that $\mathcal{C}_1$ is not homotopic to the trivial circle, you're done.

You can prove that using complex analysis. $\mathcal{C}_1$ in $\mathcal{A}$ is homeomorphic to $\gamma=\{z \in \Bbb C \ | \ |z|=2\}$ in $D=\{z\in \Bbb C \ | \ 1<|z|<3\}$. Now, $f(z)=\frac 1 z$ is holomorphic on $D$. So by Cauchy's theorem, $\int_\lambda f=0$ for every null-homotopic closed path $\lambda$.

But $\int_\gamma f\ne 0$ (easy to compute), so $\gamma$ (and thus $\mathcal{C}_1$) are not null-homotopic.

Comment: If you can show a complex analysis proof, that would be great.

Comment: I've added the proof. I'm a bit rusty in complex analysis so there may be some imprecisions, but the idea is there.

Answer (score 0):

They are homeomorphic. It doesn't really matter that they lie in the annulus, since the topology they inherit is just the same as the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.